# Como obter nome de arquivos dentro de pastas em servidor WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, rest, asp.net-web-api

Tenho um diretório *Arquivo/Uploads*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E gostaria de listar todos os arquivos, dentro deste diretório eu tenho N pastas.

o que consegui até agora está aqui.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~//Arquivos//Uploads");
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx) par obter os arquivos de um determinado diretório, configurando o terceiro paramentro `System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories` para que a busca seja feito em todos os diretório.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~//Arquivos//Uploads");
IEnumerable<string> files = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(path,
                                      "*.*",
                                       System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

<sup>***Observação:*** [`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx) também pode ser utilizado da mesma forma tendo também o 3 paramento ***a mesma definição de*** `System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories`.</sup>

> [System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(`path`, "`*.*`", `System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories`);](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms143316(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Utilizando [***Linq***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx) pode trabalhar melhor essas informações e pegar somente o nome dos arquivos:

```
var result = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, 
                      "*.*", 
                      System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(c => 
                       c.Split(new string[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Last())
                .ToArray();
```

***Referencias:***

- [EnumerateFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Directory Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [SearchOption Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143448(v=vs.110).aspx)
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx

Comment: funcionou lindamente. Porém, a resposta que tenho é do caminho ` C:\Users\renan.carlos\Source\Repos\CodingCraft\ExerciciosCo‌​dingCraft\MusicFileS‌​erver.API\Arquivos\U‌​ploads\docx\Coding Craft ASP.NET MVC 1.docx` Para eu obter apenas o nome do arquivo, eu preciso dar um Replace do fim para o começo até a primeira barra ? Ou tem uma forma melhor de fazer?  Prefere que faça uma nova pergunta  ?

Comment: @RenanCarlos fiz a edição!